# Изменение скорости движения огонька при помощи потенциометра

Tags: arduino

Я хочу, чтобы я двигал потенциометр, и менялась скорость движения огонька. Как это сделать?

```
int led_red = 2; 
int led_yellow = 3; 
int led_green = 4; 
const int lPin = 3; 
const int PPin = A0; 

int speed = 1000;
void setup() {
pinMode(led_red, OUTPUT);
pinMode(led_yellow, OUTPUT);
pinMode(led_green, OUTPUT);
pinMode(A0, INPUT);
pinMode(lPin, OUTPUT);

}
void loop() {
    int pot_val=analogRead(A0);
    int led_val=pot_val/4;
    int speed(A0);      
    digitalWrite(led_red, HIGH); 
          delay(3000);        
    digitalWrite(led_yellow, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led_red, LOW);
          delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(led_green, HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(led_red, LOW);
    digitalWrite(led_yellow, LOW);
          delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(led_yellow, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led_green, LOW);
          delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(led_yellow, LOW);
    delay(pot_val);      
}
```

Comment: Сделай через оператор For, намного меньше строчек.

Answer (score 2):

В каждом delay, вместо 3000 напишите pot_val